# Window doesn't appear in C program with SDL on mac OS X (Xcode)

Tags: c, xcode, macos

i am a beginner in C and i want to make a window with the framework SDL in Xcode ;
i read a lot of things about that but i don't resolve my issue :
i can build and run, i don't have any problems of compilation (the SDL files are well imported and linked),
but no matter the code i'm using, the windows doesn't appear..
for exemple this one :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

SDL_Window* pWindow = NULL;
pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Ma fenetre a moi",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
        640,
        480,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

SDL_Delay(3000);

// SDL_DestroyWindow(pWindow);
SDL_Quit();

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I'm on OS X 11.4 and Xcode 7.3

Hoping someone know this issue, thank you to help me !

Comment: You didn't test if the window is effectively created.

Comment: Check the errors. Especially if `pWindow` is `NULL`. You can print a human readable error message with `SDL_GetError()`.

Comment: [This guide](http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/01_hello_SDL/index2.php) suggest you must add some other functions to your code to get the windows displayed.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I don't know what was the problem but with the code of your guide it works perfectly